# Exchange 2003 Spamhaus Settings

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003, spam

I have exchange 2003 installed on Windows Server 2003, and I have a Fedora Core 9 machine with nagios installed. I use nagios to send emails about server issues which has been working fine for years until today.

When an email is sent from my fedora box I get the following error.

550 5.7.1 x.x.x.x has been blocked by Spamhaus XBL

Now I assume the IP address of my fedora box has been marked by Spamhaus as Spam. Apart from moving nagios to a different IP is there any way of getting emails through. Is there a way of bypassing Spamhaus for this one ip address?

Any help on this issue is very gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your connection filtering settings (Exchange System Manager -> Global Settings -> Message Delivery -> Connection Filtering), which is where you set your block list services, there is a white list.

At the bottom it says "Global Accept and Deny List Configuration". Click Accept and add the IP of your Nagios machine.

See [this Knowledge Base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823866) article for details.

Comment: Thank you that did the trick. So many options in exchange I never know where to find them all!